# Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have problem with jquery databale. I am getting error "Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0". sorting also not done correctly. It is sorting based on the previous columns. below is my code.

here is my code.

```
    <script>
        var contactTable = j$('[id$="safetyContractTables"]').DataTable({

                "bPaginate":true,
                "bsort":true,
                "bstateSave": true,

            });
    </script>

<apex:outputPanel id="safetyContractResult">
    <apex:pageBlock id="safetyContractBlock" title="{!IF(isDraft, 'Draft View', IF(isPublished, 'Published View', ''))}" rendered="{!OR(selectedCategory=='Contract', selectedCategory=='Safety')}"  > 

        <div display="layout" style="overflow: auto; height: 325px;" id="autowidth"> 
          <table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="safetyContractTables"> 
              <thead>
                  <tr class="headerRow">
                      <th>
                          <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'checkId');" rendered="{! checkAllEnabled}" id="selectAllCheckboxId" title="Check all to {! IF(isDraft, 'submit for QC', IF(isPublished, 'review', 'approve/reject'))}"/> 
                      </th>

                      <th style="{!IF((isDraft || isPublished), '', 'display: none;')}">Action</th>

                      <th>Country</th>
                      <th>Status</th>

                      <th style="{!IF(isPublished || isApprovalView, '', 'display: none;')}">Version</th>

                      <apex:repeat value="{!definitions}" var="par">
                          <th>
                              <div class="requiredInput" >
                                  <div class="requiredBlock" style="{!IF(par.CI_Is_Required__c, '', 'display: none;')}" />
                                  {!par.CI_Intelligence_Label__c}
                              </div>
                          </th>
                      </apex:repeat>

                      <th style="{!IF(isApprovalView, '', 'display: none;')}">Submission comments</th>

                      <th style="{!IF(isPublished, '', 'display: none;')}">Last Reviewed date</th>
                      <th style="{!IF(isPublished, '', 'display: none;')}">Next Review date</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
        <tr class="odd" style="{!IF(safetyContractRows.size>0, 'display: none;', '')}">
                      <td valign="top" colspan="20" class="dataTables_empty" style="text-align: center;">There are no records to display</td> 
                  </tr>

                  <apex:repeat value="{!safetyContractRows}" var="row">
                      <tr style="{!IF(row.collection.CF_Is_Removed__c, 'display: none;', '')}" class="dataRow {!IF(isApprovalView && MOD(row.rowIndex, 2) > 0, 'header', '')}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" id="{!row.rowIndex}">
                          <td>
                              <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!row.isChecked}" onclick="checkRows('checkId');" id="checkId" rendered="{! row.collection.CF_Status__c == 'Draft' && isDraft || isApprovalView && row.collection.CF_Status__c != 'Published' || isPublished }" title="{! IF(isDraft && row.collection.CF_Status__c == 'Draft', 'Check to submit for QC', IF(isPublished, 'Check to review', IF(isApprovalView, 'Check to approve/reject', '')))}" />
                          </td>

                          <td style="{!IF(isDraft, '', 'display: none;')}">
                              <apex:commandlink rendered="{!NOT(row.isEdit)}" action="{!addRow}" reRender="msgId,safetyContractResult" >
                                  <apex:param name="rowNumber" value="{!row.rowIndex}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}" />
                                  <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Icons,'Icons/Add_Icon.png')}" width="15" height="15" title="Add new intelligence data"/>
                              </apex:commandLink>

                               <apex:commandlink rendered="{!AND(NOT(row.isEdit), OR(adminUser, row.collection.CF_Status__c == 'Draft'))}" action="{!removeRow}" reRender="msgId,safetyContractResult">
                                  <apex:param name="rowNumber" value="{!row.rowIndex}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}" />
                                  <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Icons,'Icons/Remove_Icon.png')}" width="15" height="15" title="Delete intelligence data. Click ‘Save All’ to save the delete" />
                              </apex:commandLink>

                              <apex:commandlink value="Save" rendered="{!row.isEdit}" action="{!saveMethod}" >
                                  <apex:param name="rowNumber" value="{!row.rowIndex}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}" />
                              </apex:commandLink>

                              <apex:outputText value=" | " rendered="{!row.isEdit}" /> 

                              <apex:commandlink value="Cancel" rendered="{!row.isEdit}" onclick="cancelMethod({!row.rowIndex}); return false;"
                               > <!--reRender="msgId,safetyContractResult"-->
                                  <apex:param name="rowNumber" value="{!row.rowIndex}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}" />
                              </apex:commandLink>

                              <apex:commandlink rendered="{!NOT(row.isEdit) && row.collection.CF_Status__c != 'Submitted for QC'}" action="{!editMethod}" >
                                  <apex:param name="rowNumber" value="{!row.rowIndex}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}" />
                                  <apex:image value="/img/func_icons/util/pencil12.gif" title="Edit the intelligence data"/>
                              </apex:commandLink>
                          </td>
                          <td style="{!IF(isPublished,'','display: none;')}">
                              <apex:commandlink value="View History" action="{!collectionHistory}" reRender="historypopup">
                                  <apex:param name="rowNumber" value="{!row.rowIndex}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}"/>
                              </apex:commandlink>
                          </td>

                          <td>
                              <apex:outputField id="outputFieldCountry" value="{!row.collection.CF_Country__c}"  rendered="{!OR(NOT(row.isEdit), row.collection.Id != null)}" />

                              <div class="requiredInput" style="{!IF(AND(row.isEdit, row.collection.Id == null),'','display: none;')}">
                                  <div  class="requiredBlock"/>
                                  <apex:selectList value="{!row.collection.CF_Country__c}" size="1" >
                                      <apex:selectOptions value="{!sectionCountries}"/>
                                  </apex:selectList>
                              </div>
                          </td>

                          <td>{!row.collection.CF_Status__c}</td>

                          <td style="{!IF(isPublished || isApprovalView, '', 'display: none;')}">
                              <apex:outputField id="outputFieldVersion" value="{!row.collection.CF_Version__c}" rendered="{!isPublished || isApprovalView}"/>
                          </td>

                          <apex:repeat value="{!row.intelligencesModel}" var="intell">
                              <td>
                                  <!-- read mode -->
                                  <apex:outputText id="outputTextDraftIntelligence" value="{!intell.intelligence.CI_Draft_Intelligence__c}" escape="false" rendered="{! row.collection.CF_Status__c != 'Published' && row.collection.CF_Status__c != 'Reviewed' && NOT(row.isEdit) &&  intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c != 'Date'}"/>

                                  <apex:outputText id="outputTextDateType" value="{0, date, dd'-'MMM'-'yy}" rendered="{! NOT(row.isEdit) && intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c == 'Date'}">
                                      <apex:param value="{!intell.dateType}" /> 
                                  </apex:outputText>

                                  <apex:outputText id="outputTextPublishedIntelligence" value="{!intell.intelligence.CI_Published_Intelligence__c}" escape="false" rendered="{! (row.collection.CF_Status__c == 'Published' || row.collection.CF_Status__c == 'Reviewed') && NOT(row.isEdit) && intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c != 'Date'}"/>
                                  <!-- Start edit mode -->

                                  <div class="requiredInput">  
                                      <div class="requiredBlock" style="{!IF(intell.isRequired, '', 'display: none;')}"></div>
                                      <!--Input Long Text Area (32000) DataType-->
                                      <apex:inputTextarea id="inputTextAreaDraftLongText" value="{!intell.intelligence.CI_Draft_Intelligence__c}" 
                                      rendered="{!AND(isDraft, row.isEdit, intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c == 'Long Text Area (32000)')}"/>

                                      <!--Input Text (255) DataType-->
                                      <apex:inputText id="inputTextDraftText" value="{!intell.intelligence.CI_Draft_Intelligence__c}" 
                                      rendered="{!AND(isDraft, row.isEdit, intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c == 'Text (255)')}" />

                                      <!--Input Number DataType-->
                                      <apex:input id="inputDraftNumber" type="number" value="{!intell.numberType}" 
                                      rendered="{!AND(isDraft, row.isEdit, intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c == 'Number')}" /> 

                                      <!--Input Date DataType-->
                                      <apex:input id="inputDraftDate" type="date" value="{!intell.dateType}" styleClass="dateInput dateOnlyInput" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this , false);"
                                      rendered="{!AND(isDraft, row.isEdit, intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c == 'Date')}" /> 

                                      <!--Input Rich Text Are DataType-->
                                      <apex:inputTextarea id="inputTextAreaDraftRichText" richText="true" value="{!intell.intelligence.CI_Draft_Intelligence__c}" 
                                      rendered="{!AND(isDraft, row.isEdit, intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c == 'Rich Text Area')}" />

                                      <!--Input Single Select DataType-->
                                      <apex:selectList value="{!intell.intelligence.CI_Draft_Intelligence__c}" size="1"
                                          rendered="{!AND(isDraft, row.isEdit, intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c == 'Single Select')}">
                                          <apex:selectOptions value="{!paramIdToSelectionList[intell.intelligence.CI_Intelligence_Definiton_Name__c]}"/>
                                      </apex:selectList>

                                      <!--Input Single Select DataType-->
                                      <apex:selectList value="{!intell.multiSelected}" rendered="{!AND(isDraft, row.isEdit, intell.definition.CI_Intelligence_DataType__c == 'Multi Select')}" multiselect="true" styleClass="SelAll">
                                          <apex:selectOptions value="{!paramIdToSelectionList[intell.intelligence.CI_Intelligence_Definiton_Name__c]}"/>
                                      </apex:selectList>
                                  </div>

                                  <script>
                                      j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
                                      j$('.SelAll').SumoSelect({ selectAll: true });
                                  </script>

                                  <!-- End edit mode -->
                              </td>
                          </apex:repeat>

                          <td style="{!IF(isApprovalView, '', 'display: none;')}">
                              <apex:outputField value="{!row.collection.CI_Submission_Comments__c}" rendered="{!isApprovalView && row.collection.CF_Status__c = 'Submitted for QC'}"/>
                          </td>

                          <td style="{!IF(isPublished, '', 'display: none;')}">
                              <apex:outputtext value="{0,date,dd-MMM-YYYY}" >
                                  <apex:param value="{!row.collection.Last_Reviewed_date__c}"/>
                              </apex:outputtext>
                          </td>
                          <td style="{!IF(isPublished, '', 'display: none;')}">
                              <apex:outputText value="No Review Required For The Intelligence" rendered="{!null == row.nextReviewDate}" />
                              <apex:outputtext value="{0,date,dd-MMM-YYYY}" >
                                  <apex:param value="{!row.nextReviewDate}"/>
                              </apex:outputtext>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </apex:repeat>
                                    </tbody>
          </table>
        </div> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is possibly the most cryptic warning message that DataTables will
> show. It is a short error message as it needs to cope with all of the
> data source options that DataTables has, but flexible enough to convey
> information for each of these cases, hence why it can appear a little
> cryptic on first inspection. However, when we break it down into its
> component parts, it is actually relatively straight forward, as
> described below.
>
> Each cell in DataTables requests data, and when DataTables tries to obtain data > for a cell and is unable to do so, it will trigger a warning.......

https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

If you look at you headers rendered attributes they do not match what you columns are so sometimes the headers and columns do not match.

i.e.

Your second column header:

```
  <th style="{!IF((isDraft || isPublished), '', 'display: none;')}">Action</th>
```

and your column value

```
 <td style="{!IF(isDraft, '', 'display: none;')}">
```

Notice how if the isPublished is true the Header does display yet the column will not

Repeat that analysis for the rest of your table. If a header appears a column has to also appear

Comment: Thought it might be something like that. Maybe a quick word on how you might resolve it?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Hard to say without the code for the <tbody> since it was not given I can't offer anything better than what the documentation states.

Comment: @Eric, tbody added in the question. can you help me how can i resolve it.

Comment: @VijayKumar - See updated answer

Comment: @Eric, It worked and i am facing new issue. When trying to edit the record automatically it moving to end of the list. I want to stay on the same row.

Comment: Please change your question back to the original and start a new question @VijayKumar